# It does not return data to me when making the method call in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

My problem arises when creating the relationships in the models I create them according to the documentation of Laravel.

I have my Area Code table and my telephone table, An area code can belong to many phones, but one phone only has an area code that leaves me a one to many relationship

I will show you my models and their relationships.

Phone.php

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 * 
 * @var string
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
protected $table = 'PHONES';

/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'PHONES_ID';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'AREACODES_ID', 'PHONE', 'DATE', 'USERS_ID',
];

/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * Get the user for the phone
 * 
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

/**
 * Get the area code for the phone
 * 
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
public function areacodes(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AreaCode');
}
```

AreaCode.php

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 * 
 * @var string
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
protected $table = 'AREACODES';

/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'AREACODES_ID';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'CODE', 'CITY', 'STATESZONE_ID',
];

/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * Get the phone for the area codes
 *
 * @author Luis Morales
 */
public function phones(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Phone');
}
```

In my controller the call as follows

GenerateNumbersController.php

```
$phones = Phone::where('DATE',$searchOrCreate)
                ->chunk(500,function($phone){
                        foreach ($phone as $p) {
                        dd($p->areacodes);
                    }
        });
```

The searchOrCreate variable has a value in date format, I make a dd to $ phone and all the relationships it shows come out in null

Comment: Show us the code where you created the relation

Comment: At the end of each Model are, in the Phone.php and AreaCode.php The functions are phones and areacodes at the end of each model @Dino

Comment: Sorry I didn't formulate my question correctly. I meant the query where you create a new relation on model instance.

Comment: In the GenerateNumbersController.php controller it is seen that in the foreach I make a dd of $ p-> areacodes

And that result throws me void.

If I do a join if I generate the corresponding data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your return statement to
 return $this->belongsTo( 'App\AreaCode', 'AREACODES_ID', 'PHONES_ID');

Answer (score 3):

You are calling wrong method. dd($p->areacode); because in your phone model your model name is areacodes which does not match with the function that you call. Solution change  `dd($p->areacode);` to `dd($p->areacodes)`;

Comment: I'm checking my code and no, it was a mistake when writing the question. As it is with the $ p-> areacode it generates an error.

Comment: In some case laravel provides array. Try to use p['areacode'] once

Comment: No, it returns me null. It must be a mistake in the relationship that I can't see.

Comment: there might be convention defect would u mind to check it first, you should have followed the laravel convention like, your foreign key should be areacode_id and primary key should be id in areacodes table. So that laravel can function properly

Comment: I am following everything by company parameters, it is not personal. That is why in the models the primary keys and columns are specified as they are in the database.

Comment: Once try  return $this->belongsTo( 'App\AreaCode', 'AREACODES_ID', 'PHONES_ID');

Comment: Yes, there is the detail. It appears in the documentation and ignores it.

Put it as an answer.  

Just pass one more parameter that is $this->belongsTo ('App\AreaCode', 'AREACODES_ID')